# Swagger UI behind Nginx ingress route api are returning 404 due to wrong route

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, swagger-ui, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have K8s cluster in Azure where I deployed ASP.net core swagger, its behind an Ingress which route traffic to the service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
   
spec:
  #tls:
  #- hosts:
    #- "xx.xx.eu"
    #secretName: letsencrypt-staging
 #backend:
    #serviceName: defualt-http-backend
    #servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: api-swagger.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /swagger
        backend:
          serviceName: development-manager
          servicePort: 80
```

once I navigate to api-swagger.azure.com/swagger i got the interface, but when i try API calls i keep getting 404 and its because the route is wrong

```
curl -X GET "https://api-swagger.cloudapp.azure.com/api/v1/DevelopmentManager/batches?customerId=1" -H  "accept: text/plain"
```

how I can get the right routing where the API calls with their parameters are routed to the IP of the development service instead of using the ingress domain https://api-swagger.cloudapp.azure.com

Comment: "routed to the IP of the development service instead of using the ingress domain" if it's behind an ingress server that should not work. What you need is, you ingress domain but prefix all paths with the "/swagger" (as you're using it in you kubernetes config).It's described in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I fixed it with adding new route like this ** - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: development-manager
          servicePort: 80 ** is this the best practice to do it ?

Comment: There is no best practice but just your decision. If you want your backend service to be available in a sub directory, you have configure this path in kubernetes and configure your app to work with this settings. If you want your app in the root directory, no additional configuration is required in your app.

Comment: Its very clear for me now, Thanks a lot @ChristophLütjen :)